# How to Upload PDF File on Azure Blob Storage via Node.js?

Tags: node.js, azure-blob-storage

```
  const blobServiceClient = await BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString);
  const containerClient = await blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(container);
  const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(fileName);

  const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.upload(content, content.length);
  console.log(uploadBlobResponse);
  console.log(`FIle upload successfully on cloud ${uploadBlobResponse.requestId}`);
```

i am trying like this, but blockBlobClient.upload() needs content, i converted file in base64 and sent it into content, but i am having issue, file is uplaoded but corrupted. any help please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the SDK, the [upload method](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#upload-httprequestbody--number--blockblobuploadoptions-) construct is `upload(HttpRequestBody, number, BlockBlobUploadOptions)`, the content is HttpRequestBody, check the parameter it requires

> Blob, string, ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView or a function which returns
>   a new Readable stream whose offset is from data source beginning.

So maybe you could try [uploadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#uploadfile-string--blockblobparalleluploadoptions-), just use the file path to upload, I have tried this way it works.

Also, you could use [uploadStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#uploadstream-readable--undefined---number--undefined---number--blockblobuploadstreamoptions-) to upload the file readable stream.

Comment: Thank you so much uploadFile helped, plus when its upload where will be my url in response, there is no url in response so that i save my file path in database, kindly help thank you in advance.